# Can't create locale strings.xml in Android Studio 3.5.1

Tags: android-studio

I want to add a localized strings.xml for my app using Android Studio 3.5.1. After having chosen the language, then I select the country (under Specific Region Only column). However, every time I want to click OK, the selected field always go back to Any Region. Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: type directory name as values-en-rUS or something like that (last two letters should be ISO 2 letter shorthand for the country)

Comment: Not sure what was going on, but it works today. Perhaps after all the caches have been cleared and gradle has been rebuilt.